# stop animation in angularjs when filtering ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-animate

I have an angular web application when loads a list of "Notes" into a scope array called `notes`.

This list is filtered within a `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<div class="noteClass" ng-repeat="n in notes | propertyFilter: 'Fields.noteTabNumber' : selectedTab">
```

This all works fine, and I have added some CSS animations into my CSS file so that when a new item is added into the `notes` array, it animates into the scene.

```
div.noteClass.ng-enter,
div.noteClass.ng-leave,
div.noteClass.ng-move {
    //my animations here
}

div.noteClass.ng-enter,
div.noteClass.ng-move
 {
    //my further animation functions
}

div.noteClass.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
div.noteClass.ng-move.ng-move-active {
    /// finished animations
}
```

My issue is with the filter, as you can see, the list is filtered with a custom filter called `propertyFitler` which is filters the notes based on which 'tab' a user has selected.

Which is a simple `UL`:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{selected: selectedTab==1}">...</li>
    <li ng-class="{selected: selectedTab==2}">...</li>
    <li ng-class="{selected: selectedTab==3}">...</li>
</ul>
```

When ever the user clicks a different tab, the animation for the items fire, **rather than simply filtering the list instantly**.

How can I animate a new item into the list, but when a user filters the list via the `LI` item, dont animate the change in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject the `$animate` service into your controller, then whatever callback you have for clicking a tab should first call `$animate.enabled(false)`. This will disable animations. Then just call `$animate.enabled(true)` once the page has refreshed. Knowing when to enable the animations again may be the tricky part. Easiest thing to do is just use `$timeout` to disable animations for half a second or so. If you don't like that, there are some blog posts out there about working out when `ngRepeat` completes its work. Or perhaps there is a really obvious and clean solution I have not considered.

Comment: so how would I use this exactly? Do I need to set `noAnimate = true` when the user clicks the list item, then change the `selectedTab` property? Im not too familiar with the service decorators...

Comment: OK, cancel my last. New answer is much easier.

Comment: that seemed to do the trick, I did have to add the timeout unfortunately, which is a bit of a hack, but works in my case